# Is there a way to access a log of all recent activity that happened on my computer (MB Air)?

Tags: wireless-networking, security, event-log

So I logged onto this unrestricted WiFi network, and I just want to be safe and make sure no one has been messing around on my computer. Anyone know a way to access a log of all recent activity on my computer? I have a MacBook Air running on Mountain Lion. Thank you in advance for all of your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can find your machines logs at `Applications > Utilities > Console` or by using Terminal and navigating to `/Library/Logs`.